# why my iFrame redirects to other page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, redirect, iframe

I'm making a little website with a little radio online player, the radio is a local station from Bogotá... I'm getting the player with this code:

```
<iframe src="http://ec2-54-196-129-174.compute-1.amazonaws.com/radio_player/code.php?t=id&amp;code=q6avqg==" style="width: auto;height: auto;float: right;clear: both;display: block;min-height: 200px;overflow: auto;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;" border="0">
```

I'm using PHP to get it from mySQL BD and printing it into my page... When I run it into localhost, it works perfectly, but when I upload the script to the website, the iFrame redirects to other x page... why that happens?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this...

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" sandbox=""></iframe>
```

sandbox can have parameters like allow-forms allow-scripts, but you can keep it simply="" that will save ur day..!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The url you're using for the iframe responds with:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    top.location.href='http://www.emisorasdominicanasonline.com';
</script>
<noscript>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.google.com/">
</noscript>
```

It's not clear to me why noscript sends the browser somewhere different from the script tag, but that's why you're seeing that result.

Comment: "noscript" works when the browser does not support javascript. 
So it should redirect to the top.location.href='...' mentioned page.

Comment: @Riad I know... that's why it's so perplexing that they don't match up.

Comment: But, why in my localhost works alright?, my localhost load the player correctly, but no in the website